# Textract's start_document_text_detection stuck on IN_PROGRESS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sns, amazon-textract

```
    s3client = boto.client('s3', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    textract = boto.client('textract', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    response = textract.start_document_text_detection(
        DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Name':'name'}
        },
        NotificationChannel={
            'SNSTopicArn': 'arn', 'RoleArn': 'role'        
        },
        OutputConfig={
            'S3Bucket': 'bucket',
            'S3Prefix': 'prefix'
        }
        )
```

the SNS topic never gets published because the job never completes. Whenever I put the response['JobId'] into get_document_text_detection, it has a job status of IN_PROGRESS. What's going on?

Comment: did this ever resolve? going thru this right now-

Comment: Ditto. I'm dealing with this too. I have a particular doc that always comes back IN_PROGRESS. It's only one page and I'm only processing this doc. I have my polling set to the longest: 20 seconds.